# What should I replace calls to coreRegistry with?

Tags: magento2.4, register

I have a redirect for new customers that uses coreRegistery->registery, but that's been depricated. What's the new way to check for is_new_account?

```
 if ($this->coreRegistry->registry('is_new_account')) {
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $result */
            $result = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
            $result->setUrl($this->url->getUrl('<page name>'));
            return $result;
        }
```

Comment: Your goal is to redirect customer to some specific page, after register?

Comment: Yes. That's what I'm doing now, but I expect it to stop working soon

Answer (score 1):

You will need to store the data into a session and grab it to your `PHTML with the help of service classes or data providers.

You can check-in details here: https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/alternatives-for-deprecated-registry-class-magento-2-3/

For data providers, check this: https://github.com/magento/graphql-ce/blob/7990b83d7d27efdaa89d60292e37058d5b78c79f/app/code/Magento/QuoteGraphQl/Model/CartItem/DataProvider/CustomizableOption.php

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This isn't for a phtml page, it's for a redirect function. Specifically, I'm using aroundGetRedirect to redirect users to a page with a form if they've created a new account.

Comment: You can still get the data in your controller or anywhere else. Try the session approach.